# What kind of "-ware" are vases and cups?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Mary makes tea cups, tea bowls, vases and other __ware at the pottery
>   workshop.

If it were just tea cups and tea bowls I could write teaware. However, vases aren't teaware.

What's the correct word to use in this case? (Say, if the stuff is made of clay?)

Comment: "Chinaware", perhaps?

Comment: Stoneware or earthenware, depending on technique

Comment: @Stefan Good suggestions! What if the stuff is made of clay?

Comment: You might want a 'products' after 'X-ware' for balance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure? My construction seems to be more common: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22and+other+chinaware%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1855&bih=934

Comment: @alex, FYI, chinaware (more commonly just shortened to china) refers only to items made from porcelain, not the type of clay items people make in a pottery workshop.

Comment: Just a thought: you could also consider using a different word altogether. You could use "ceramics" as a general term for pottery. Or you could group the items by function and call them "containers".

Comment: Porcelain, earthenware and stoneware all are made from clay.

Comment: I'm not saying it's mandatory, but I'd use it here after 'tea cups, tea bowls, vases', for balance, as I say. As a standalone, as in the examples you link to, X-ware is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whatever material the dishes are made of, you can just add -ware to the end of the adjective that describes it:

- **clayware**
- glassware
- paperware
- plasticware
- woodenware

This does not apply to stone (stoneware is actually a type of clayware).

Please note, though, that some of these are more common than others. For example, "glassware" is common, whereas "paperware" is not, and may sound too contrived in a casual context. In the case of clay, as Stefan mentioned in the comments, it's more common to call dishes "**stoneware**" or "**earthenware**", depending on how it was made. However, if you don't know what type it is, you can just call it "**clayware**" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clayware).

Comment: Cray comes from the earth. So maybe it's correct to call it "earthenware"?

Comment: @alex No, earthenware refers to a specific technique for how the clay was fired (lower temperature). If you're not sure if that technique was used, don't use that word.

Comment: Note that this answer does not match British English (which is not a criticism, but may be important to some). *Clayware* is unheard-of.

Comment: @Andrew: *Clayware* is virtually unheard-of in the U.S., as well. Both  *stoneware* and *earthenware* are relatively common (although I couldn't actually tell you the difference myself.

Comment: *Earthenware* is the more primitive form of pottery (although Wikipedia says that people started producing stoneware nearly 4000 years ago, so it's not an advanced industrial technique).